# Elegant way to map a list of functions onto a variable in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have an input variable:

```py
var = 10
```

and I have a list of functions:

```
functions = [
  lambda x: x + 1,
  lambda x: x + 10,
  lambda x: x + 42
]
```

Is there an elegant way to map the functions over the variable to get a list output?

```py
# elegant one-liner here
11
20
52
```

P.S. not `[f(var) for f in functions]`, please, something with `map`.

Comment: Use what you have. What's the problem with it, what do you consider "inelegant"? Or if you want to use `map`, ... _use `map`_. But `list(map(...))` is generally better written as a list comprehension, as recommended right from [Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists).

Comment: why you need map?

Comment: `map(lambda f:f(var),functions)` is effectively a restatement of your list comprehension, but it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: right, and to get list output I’d just pass the map to print, like `print(*map…)`. but realistically, this would probably be a bit cleaner using a comprehension approach.

Comment: map is used to apply a function to an iterable of values generally. in your case, you have the opposite, one value and and an iterable of functions

Comment: There's a reason Guido thought `map` was obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` for this, as the question suggests:

```
map(lambda f: f(var), functions)
```

For future reference, `lambda f:f(var)` takes a function, and applies that function to a value - which is what we want to do for each element of our list, so then we `map` it to our list, to apply this lambda function to each element of our list, calling that element with the variable `var` as an argument.

However, as jonrsharpe mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73779630/elegant-way-to-map-a-list-of-functions-onto-a-variable-in-python#comment130279734_73779630), if you're not just iterating over the map then a list comprehension is more in line with the standard Python style guide.

As a final aside for future reference, even if you're just iterating over it you could consider using a generator expression, which has many of the benefits of `map`.

Comment: even though OP could be skilled, I think it might be nice to have an explanation, just in case others reading it too.

Comment: That's a great idea! I'll add one.

Comment: nice one, elegant indeed!

Comment: @NathanMcCoy You have an unusual definition of "elegant" then :-P. Your list comprehension is really the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`apply`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#apply):

```
var = 10

functions = [
  lambda x: x + 1,
  lambda x: x + 10,
  lambda x: x + 42
]

result = map(apply, functions, [[var]] * len(functions))

print(result)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BCoMwEETv@xVzTNocVHoq9EtCDtvWUiGuS4yiX58GCl48zhvmje75O0lXysoJD7QN0WeRVx4mmWv2BEQen2/GdseGK1p3Rs2Z3ToKRKmfl5irZ2Q1rBp3h0Pv4H19DQEXxF7MUVhLpGmQbP57W8oP)):

```
[11, 20, 52]
```

Ah, good old times...

Python 3:

```
from operator import methodcaller
from functools import partial

var = 10

functions = [
  lambda x: x + 1,
  lambda x: x + 10,
  lambda x: x + 42
]

result = list(map(methodcaller('__call__', var), functions))

print(result)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITv@xR7M8EeWvUggk8iEmKbYiB/bLZSnz7GiiL0NjN8zEx68j2G/TFRKSNFjzEZ0hwJrU@RGL2pwNBr5wzBQoxT6DlGl79I0sRWO4CHJjxj1wIsjI0hV38BRKf9bdA4n3DGLXbNOmrX2WEHVwAgkyfHtcjZzMLrJP4/iY1Sb6XUpsF6QDb4G5cSIJENLD4dspQX)):

```
[11, 20, 52]
```

Comment: Ah, it's deprecated. That's a shame. I'm mildly surprised that there isn't something like this buried somewhere deep in the bowels of the stdlib, but I can see the rationale for removing this sort of construct. And yes, if the situation came up, I suppose you could indeed write your own version. Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: @iteratedwalls Added something for Python 3. Not sure which one is worse :-)

Comment: the `apply` technique is cool!

Comment: @iteratedwalls Don't be too upset. There is a [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/operator.html#operator.call) in Python 3.11.

Comment: @MechanicPig Nice. [Issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88185) for its introduction.

Comment: The `partial` in the answer of Python3 version seems unnecessary? I got the same result after removing it.

Comment: @MechanicPig Ah yes, thanks. Removed. It took some fiddling to make it work at all (I rarely use those functions) and that was a remnant of an early attempt. Now it actually looks somewhat reasonable.